# Gnuplot: plotting only specific values of the dataset using lines or linespoints

Tags: plot, dataset, expression, conditional-statements, gnuplot

Let's suppose my dataset is like this:

```
0 0.3
1 0.12
2 0.4
3 0.6
4 0.9
...
10 0.23
11 0.6
...
20 0.34
21 0.4
...
```

and I'd like to plot values of both columns only if `$1 % 10 == 0`, i.e., `(0,0.3), (10,0.23), (20,0.34)` and so on... Now, I've written the following conditional script:

```
plot "data.csv" using 1:(int($1)%10==0?$2:0/0) title 'r=1' with linespoints linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'blue'
```

The problem is that lines are not shown, but only points.

[image]

This is because, for all rows where the condition is not satisfied, the corresponding value is undefined. Anyway, what I need is quite different; I want those specific values to be just ignored, not to set to undefined. Is there a way to do that just using gnuplot (not awk and so on)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you have all intermediate steps, i.e., full data for number (which is suspect based on your axis labelled iterations), you best use the `every` option

```
plot "data.csv" every 10 with linespoints
```

Otherwise, I would use `awk` inside your script for simplicity

```
plot "<awk '$1%10==0' data8" with linespoints
```

The probably with your original script, is that the points are shown, but with value infinity. It is a feature that these lines are not shown.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bernhard. I didn't know the "every" option; it works as I want!